# PopupWindow with swiping scrollable views

Tags: android, gallery, scrollable

I'm trying to create a `Popupindow` in which the views can be changed by swiping. Each view should also be scrollable when larger than the popup window. I also want to move only one view when swiping. I can't find any simple way to do that (the Gallery move several views when swiping).

Is there any widget I missed or do I have to implement everything to achieve that (with `ViewFlipper` and gesture detection for instance)?

Anybody can help with the best way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found and ended up using the fantastic [HorizontalPager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager).